# In trNgGrid, how to get filtered data for export, or get current filter's value

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular's trNgGrid library to display a table of data and trying to export data. On some occasions I want to export the filtered data.

My question is:
   How to get the data records filtered by the active filter or get the active filter's value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this example helping? See *Grid Configuration* - http://moonstorm.github.io/trNgGrid/release/#/GlobalOptions

Using `filtered-items="myGridFilteredItems"` attribute you should be able to access filtered array.